# Algorithm to find out all the possible positions

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I need an algorithm to find out all the possible positions of a group of pieces in a chessboard. Like finding all the possible combinations of the positions of a number N of pieces.

For example in a chessboard numbered like cartesian coordinate systems any piece would be in a position

```
(x,y) where 1 <= x <= 8 and 1 <= y <= 8
```

I'd like to get an algorithm which can calculate for example for 3 pieces all the possible positions of the pieces in the board. But I don't know how can I get them in any order. I can get all the possible positions of a single piece but I don't know how to mix them with more pieces.

```
for(int i = 0; i<= 8; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<= 8; j++){
        System.out.println("Position: x:"+i+", y:"+j);
    }
}
```

How can I get a good algoritm to find all the posible positions of the pieces in a chessboard?

Thanks.

Comment: any restrictions on the positions? or do you just want all possible selections of n positions?

Comment: Do they have to be legal positions (e.g. one knight on white, one on black, no pawns on first two ranks etc?)

Comment: @Nick no restrictions at all. I just need all the possible configurations of a numbrer of items (I just added the example of the chess to make it simpler but I is for any "map" to find all the possible distributions of the elements).

Comment: @DNA no, I don't mind if they are legal or not. Just that 2 pieces can't be in the same position.

Comment: @Nick the only restriction is that 2 pieces can't be in the same position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got 8x8 board, so total of 64 squares.

Populate a list containing these 64 sqaures [let it be `list`], and find all of the possibilities [recursively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion): Each step will "guess" one point, and invoke the recursve call to find the other points.

Pseudo code:

```
choose(list,numPieces,sol):
   if (sol.length == numPieces): //base clause: print the possible solution
       print sol
       return
   for each point in list:
       sol.append(point) //append the point to the end of sol
       list.remove(point)
       choose(list,numPieces,sol) //recursive call
       list.add(point)  //clean up environment before next recursive call
       sol.removeLast()
```

invoke with `choose(list,numPieces,[])` where `list` is the pre-populated list with 64 elements, and `numPieces` is the pieces you are going to place.

Note: This solution assumes pieces are **not** identical, so `[(1,2),(2,1)]` and `[(2,1),(1,2)]` are both good different solutions.

**EDIT:**

Just a word about complexity, since there are `(n^2)!/(n^2-k)!` possible solutions for your problem - and you are looking for all of them, any algorithm will suffer from exponential run time, so trying to invoke it with just 10 pieces, will take ~400 years

[In the above notation, `n` is the width and length of the board, and `k` is the number of pieces]

Comment: +1 for the word about complexity (with n being the height and the length of the board, and k being the number of pieces).

Comment: @DaveBall: Thanks, I forgot mentioning what `n` and `k` stands for in the answer. I editted it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive algorithm to generate all possiblities:

```
void combine(String instr, StringBuffer outstr, int index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < instr.length(); i++)
    {
       outstr.append(instr.charAt(i));
       System.out.println(outstr);
       combine(instr, outstr, i + 1);
       outstr.deleteCharAt(outstr.length() - 1);
   }
}
```

combine("abc", new StringBuffer(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you should consider that some firgure may come block some potential position for figures that can reach them on the empty board. I guess it is the most tricky part.
So you should build some set of vertexes (set of board states) that is reached from some single vertex (initial board state).

The first algorithm that comes to my mind:

Pre-conditions:

- Order figures in some way to form circle.
- Assume initial set of board states (S0) to contain single element which represents inital board state.

Actions

1. Choose next figure to extend set of possible positions
2. For each state of board within S(n) walk depth-first all possible movements that new board states and call it F(n) (frame).
3. Form S(n+1) = S(n) ∪ F(n).
4. Repeat steps till all frames of updates during whole circle pass will not be empty.

This is kind of mix breath-first and depth-first search